# What would be the alternative to active objects in jira plugin development?

Tags: jira, active-objects

This [issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-25808) here says that trasnactions don't work in jira.

I guess that means that active objects are useless, and unusable in a production environment.

So what would be the alternative?

I'm new to jira plugin development, and I'm working on my first project, doing the java backend part. I had a very hard time getting the active objects stuff to work, and already spent(wasted?) a week on it.

I need full database support, so moving to a key-value pair system would not be enough.

Any help would be appreciated.

edit, trying to clarify:

I'm creating a plugin for jira, that enables us to track users time logging.
I want to save users input of worktime data, and show it in a meaningful way.

> (warning) Please note, JIRA currently does not support transactions
>   for Active Objects (as of JIRA 6.0).

```
public void someMethod(final ActiveObjects ao)
{
    ao.executeInTransaction(new TransactionCallback<Object>()
    {
        @Override
        public Object doInTransaction()
        {
            // do something with AO. According to the docs, this does not actually run in a transaction.
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

So if I still want to use dbs in jira, what would be the alternative to active objects? As far as I know, databases without transactions make no sense.

[Cross posted](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/269720/what-would-be-the-alternative-to-active-objects)...

Comment: reworded..so how about it now?

Comment: There are a few issues with this question: What are you actually trying to accomplish? You're doing a JIRA Plugin project. What is it?  What do you need persisted?  What do you mean by "Full database support"? What code are you actually having a problem with ("already spent(wasted?) a week on it")? Unless we have something more concrete, this feels like a JIRA support question and *not* a programming question. I realize you want this to be a programming question, so can you help us out with a better understanding of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

I choose JdbcTemplate, ao is used just for create table